# How to set opacity of each image when merging multiple png images in PHP

Tags: php, png, gd

I am trying to merge different .png images into one single image keeping the transparency but I am unable to set opacity for each image before combining. Here is what I am doing

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng($images[0]);
  imagealphablending($img, true);
  imagesavealpha($img, true);
  foreach($images as $fn) {
   $cur = imagecreatefrompng($fn);   
   imagealphablending($cur, true);
   imagesavealpha($cur, true);
   imagecopy($img, $cur, 0, 0, 0, 0, 512, 512);
   imagedestroy($cur);
  }
  imagepng($img);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this function for each image: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php#82162 But images should have a PNG extension. I didn't try it but maybe it will help you.

Comment: Or try this build in function: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageopacity.php

Comment: I have tried second one but it didn't work. First function is taking too long to render images . I want quick way of doing this . any other solution ? Thanks by the way

Comment: imagecopymerge() doesn't do what you need?

Comment: No, I did try imagecopymerge() but I lost tranparency.

Comment: Do your images employ a palette? Try converting them to true color with imagepalettetotruecolor() first.